# Lookin for some way to copy XAML MenuItem properties to a button in a single step

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Assume that i have multiple menu-items like this one:

```
<MenuItem Name="MenuItemDownload" Command="{Binding DownloadCommand}"
          Header="Download"
          ToolTip="Some long description of whats happening...">
    <MenuItem.Icon>
        <Image Source="/Resources/download.png"
               Width="{Binding Source.PixelWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource self}}" />
    </MenuItem.Icon>
</MenuItem>
```

For some of this menu-items i have toolbar-buttons, currently defined like this:

```
<Button Command="{Binding DownloadCommand}"
        ToolTip="{Binding ElementName=MenuItemDownload, Path=ToolTip}">
    <Image Source="{Binding ElementName=MenuItemDownload, Path=Icon.Source}"
           Width="{Binding Source.PixelWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource self}}" />
</Button>
```

This works. And I can define everything once and transfer it to the button. But I am lookin for something like "this is menu-item is your reference element. copy/bind everything thats defined and relevant to you"...   Something like

```
<Button IsMirroring="{Binding ElementName=MenuItemDownload}" />
```

I am sure its possible... But how? Please give me some keywords or hints :)

Comment: It looks like you already used a possible solution for the image source and tooltip... why don't you start by doing the same thing for the command and everything else you want to copy. Then start worrying how to replace the ElementName syntax with a different element transfer technique?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solution stays close to your `IsMirroring="{Binding ElementName=MenuItemDownload}"` idea. Create an attached property and initialize bindings in code behind:

```
public static class Attached
{
    public static MenuItem GetMirrorSource(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (MenuItem)obj.GetValue(MirrorSourceProperty);
    }

    public static void SetMirrorSource(DependencyObject obj, MenuItem value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(MirrorSourceProperty, value);
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MirrorSource.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MirrorSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("MirrorSource", typeof(MenuItem), typeof(Attached), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnMirrorSourceChanged)));

    private static void OnMirrorSourceChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var button = d as Button;
        if (button != null)
        {
            // initialize bindings and content image
            button.SetBinding(Button.CommandProperty, new Binding("Command") { Source = e.NewValue });
            button.SetBinding(Button.ToolTipProperty, new Binding("ToolTip") { Source = e.NewValue });

            var content = button.Content as Image;
            if (content == null)
            {
                content = new Image();
                content.Stretch = Stretch.None;
                button.Content = content;
            }
            content.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty, new Binding("Icon.Source") { Source = e.NewValue });
        }
    }
}
```

Usage with namespace declaration `xmlns:local=...`:

```
<Button local:Attached.MirrorSource="{Binding ElementName=MenuItemDownload}"/>
```

As long as the buttons are statically assigned to menu items, this should be sufficient. If the mirrored button changes a lot it might be better to avoid the creation of new bindings for every change.

Note I opted for `Image.Stretch = Stretch.None` instead of binding the width, because I think thats your actual intention - might be wrong.

Comment: Yes, the menu-items are statically assigend, some of them are mirrored to the toolbar. None of the mirrored-properties changes, only the enabled status. But what do you mean by "new bindings for every change"? And yes, `Image.Stretch` was also my first intention. But it did not work - the image is resized from 16x16 to about 128x128. Others are also resized - but to different sizes... I think thats caused by really strange DPI values of the icons. I'll have a look if there is an update availiable for the icon-pack...

Comment: @Michael If the menu items where not statically assigned, then `OnMirrorSourceChanged` would re-run with each change, running it multiple times on the same button element. The code is just not optimized for such a scenario but thats not really relevant for your case. You can of course stick with the width binding - just construct the binding like the others but with `RelativeSource` self.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'll keep that in mind for attached-properties. Yeah, had to google a bit how to use `RelativeSource` in code but it works now :)